# React compiler won't accept my .map function as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can't get to get the complier acknoledge that I am passing an array to the map function, so I keep getting an error that my .map function is not a function. I just want to list links in an unordered list.

I've tried assigning the data to an generic array with in the function, and now it's greatgrandparent's state, where it's assigned is set up to be an array.  I even made a close replica of the code off of the reactjs' site to accomplish what I want out of the logic to use the map function.

```
const mobileMenu = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={classes.MobileMenu}>
        <h1 id={classes.MobileMenu__Title}>Water Resources</h1>
        <div>
            <button id={classes.LoginButton}>Login</button>
            <button id={classes.RegisterButton}>Register</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        {menuLinks(props.links)}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

calls

```
const menuLinks = (links) => {
    console.log (links);
    let Links = links;
    const listLinks = Links.map((Links) =>
    (<li key={Links.index.toString()}>
    <a href={Links.link}>{Links.name}</a>
    </li>));
    return (

        <ul>           
            {listLinks()}        
        </ul>
);}
```

Debugger states that object is a link array, but I keep on getting the error that the list links function is undefined.

```
mainlinks = [
      {name: "Home", link: "#Home"},
      {name: "Calculator", link: "#Calculator"},
      {name: "Reference", link: "#reference"},
      {name: "About", link: "#About"}
]
```

that is set in state.
​​​
​​

​

Comment: what does `Array.isArray(links)` return?

Comment: Check if `links` is an `array` with `Array.isArray(links)` and in case of false, if links is an `array-like` object, i.e, it have indexed properties and a length property, then you can use `[...links].map()`.

Comment: It says false.  Now I'm totally lost.  @Shidersz

Comment: @Serial_Seth Then, proceed with the spreading of the links inside an array, like I have mentioned. Or, alternatively, use [Array.from(links)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then use `map()`, i.e, `Array.from(links).map(<your_code_here>);`

Comment: I added the spread operator all the way up to my original array, but I am getting a type error (export default function _nonIterableSpread() {
  throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance");
} all the way up to the og array that looks like as above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here,

```
{listLinks()}
```

You are trying to execute function listLinks which is not a function.

Just use {listLinks} without parenthesis like below,

```
const menuLinks = (links) => {
        console.log(links);
        const listLinks = links.map(link =>{
           return (
              <li key={link.name}>
                  <a href={link.link}>{link.name}</a>
              </li>
           )
        }); 
        return (
            <ul>           
             {listLinks}        
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

---

If you are receiving group of object then here you can find iterate over object https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8

Comment: I know that's wrong I missed it when posting.  I tried that in desperation to make the code work.

Comment: You were correct earlier when you suggested that I was receiving a group of objects.  @ravibagul91

Comment: Looking more to make my original array more typesafe, vs working with each linked object indivisually.  There has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this ?

```
const menuLinks = (links) => {    
    return (
        <ul>           
         {
            links.map(link => (
              <li key={link.name}>
                <a href={link.link}>{link.name}</a>
              </li>
            ))
         }        
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Edit : I saw some stuff that were weird you're using "Links" for the array name and the map element name i had some issues with this

In the return, listLinks is not a function but a new array

Or like people said in the comments maybe it's not an array :x